# My code is not functioning the way i want to

Tags: python, if-statement

So im practicing python by making simple games. I don't know what I did wrong here, when **game over** shows and I input 'yes' to play again, it breaks. That shouldn't supposed to happen. Any improvements is appreciated.

```
def play():
    tries = 3
    name = input('Enter your name: ')
    start = input('Hi {}! Do you want to play? (Yes/No)'.format(name.upper()))
    while True and tries > 0 and start.lower() == 'yes':
        n = input('What is the number next to 5? : ')
        try:
            i = float(n)
            if i == 6:
                print('Correct!')
                start = input('Do you want to play again? (Yes/No)')

            else:
                tries -= 1
                if tries > 1:
                    print('You have', tries, 'tries left. Try again!')
                elif tries == 1:
                    print('You only have', tries, 'try left.')
                elif tries == 0:
                    print("""It's game over for you""", name.upper())
                    start = input('Do you want to play again? (Yes/No)')
                if start.lower() == 'no':
                        print('Sorry to have you go')
                        break

        except:
            print('Please enter a number: ')
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    play()
```

Comment: Please improve the title to make it more specific to your problem.

Comment: You need to set "tries" back to 3. Otherwise the "while" loop breaks

Comment: @equinox_xy and how exactly do you want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it:

```py
def play():
    tries = 3
    name = input('Enter your name: ')
    start = input('Hi {}! Do you want to play? (Yes/No)'.format(name.upper()))
    while True and tries > 0 and start.lower() == 'yes':
        n = input('What is the number next to 5? : ')
        try:
            i = float(n)
            if i == 6:
                print('Correct!')
                start = input('Do you want to play again? (Yes/No)')
                if start.lower() == 'yes':
                    tries = 3
            else:
                tries -= 1
                if tries > 1:
                    print('You have', tries, 'tries left. Try again!')
                elif tries == 1:
                    print('You only have', tries, 'try left.')
                elif tries == 0:
                    print("""It's game over for you""", name.upper())
                    start = input('Do you want to play again? (Yes/No)')
                    if start.lower() == 'no':
                            print('Sorry to have you go')
                            break
                    if start.lower() == 'yes':
                        tries = 3

        except:
            print('Please enter a number: ')
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    play()
```

edit and improve code:

```py
def paly_agein():
    start = input('Do you want to play again? (Yes/No)')
    return start

def play():
    tries = 3
    name = input('Enter your name: ')
    start = input('Hi {}! Do you want to play? (Yes/No)'.format(name.upper()))
    while True and tries > 0 and start.lower() == 'yes':
        n = input('What is the number next to 5? : ')
        try:
            i = float(n)
            if i == 6:
                print('Correct!')
                tries = 3 if paly_agein().lower() == 'yes' else 0
                
            else:
                tries -= 1
                if tries > 1:
                    print('You have', tries, 'tries left. Try again!')
                elif tries == 1:
                    print('You only have', tries, 'try left.')
                elif tries == 0:
                    print("""It's game over for you""", name.upper())
                    tries = 3 if paly_agein().lower() == 'yes' else 0
                    
        except:
            print('Please enter a number: ')
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    play()
```

Answer (score -1):

your problem was that if you said yes you didn't give him more tries and that you need to put it when the tries are 0 because that when you care if the answer is yes or no.

```py
def play():
    tries = 3
    name = input('Enter your name: ')
    start = input('Hi {}! Do you want to play? (Yes/No)'.format(name.upper()))
    while tries > 0 and start.lower() == 'yes':
        n = input('What is the number next to 5? : ')
        try:
            i = float(n)
            if i == 6:
                print('Correct!')
                start = input('Do you want to play again? (Yes/No)')
            else:
                tries -= 1
                if tries > 1:
                    print('You have', tries, 'tries left. Try again!')
                elif tries == 1:
                    print('You only have', tries, 'try left.')
                elif tries == 0:
                    print("""It's game over for you""", name.upper())
                    start = input('Do you want to play again? (Yes/No)')
                    if start.lower() == 'yes':
                        tries = 3
                    elif start.lower() == 'no':
                        print('Sorry to have you go')
                        break


        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a number: ')
```

Comment: What corrections were made? Please explain